# compare two graphs with different number of nodes

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Is there a distance measure between two graphs with different number of nodes?

To be specific, let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be their adjacency matrices respectively. When the two graphs have the same number of nodes, and if we consider the nodes as aligned, we could simply take $\|W_1 - W_2\|_F$ . If the nodes are not aligned, we could solve a graph matching problem and use its objective value as the measure.

However, what if the two graphs are of different number of nodes?

Comment: You can define a continuous relaxation of the notion of alignment between vertices, and then optimize over that, as was done, for example, in the paper Coordinated Optimal Transport on Graphs by myself and Yihe Dong https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.03892

Comment: Depends on what you want the distance measure to measure? You could add isolated filler vertices to the smaller graph but that may or may not be useful in your context.

Comment: The graph edit distance is a very flexible tool to express distance between graphs. However, it is very costly to compute.

Comment: @WillSawin I skim through paper. It seems that one has to solve an optimal transport problem, and take the optimal objective as the distance. Kind of similar to what I speculated in the question. Is it possible to come up with an upper/lower bound or surrogate to the optimal objective, so that we can avoid doing the optimization?

Comment: @JiajiHuang Not that I know of. One can try to vary the objective function to make such a surrogate possible to construct. However, one will face the challenge for any kind of rigorous surrogate or approximation (rather than heuristic methods like gradient descent, which often works pretty well but has no provable guarantee in this setting) that a surrogate that is too strong would give a solution to the graph isomorphism problem, and no (polynomial-time) solution is known.